# Customizing user_nicename in wp_users table in wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

By default wordpress will santitize the contents written to `user_nicename` column in `wp_users` table. It will remove spaces, some special characters and change uppercase to lowercase. Will it be possible to update `user_nicename` column without sanitizations?

Comment: Hi :) What are the specifications and what do you want to do.

Comment: I want unsanitized nice_name.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the **pre_user_nicename** filter. You can read on it here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_nicename/ The filter is applied right after the nicename is sanitized, but we can still access the unsanitized data. This is from wp-includes/user.php

```
 /*
 * If a nicename is provided, remove unsafe user characters before using it.
 * Otherwise build a nicename from the user_login.
 */
if ( ! empty( $userdata['user_nicename'] ) ) {
    $user_nicename = sanitize_user( $userdata['user_nicename'], true );
    if ( mb_strlen( $user_nicename ) > 50 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'user_nicename_too_long', __( 'Nicename may not be longer than 50 characters.' ) );
    }
} else {
    $user_nicename = mb_substr( $user_login, 0, 50 );
}
$user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user_nicename );
// Store values to save in user meta.
$meta = array();
/**
 * Filters a user's nicename before the user is created or updated.
 *
 * @since 2.0.3
 *
 * @param string $user_nicename The user's nicename.
 */
$user_nicename = apply_filters( 'pre_user_nicename', $user_nicename );
$raw_user_url = empty( $userdata['user_url'] ) ? '' : $userdata['user_url'];
```

You can still access the unmodified nicename entered by the user with the $userdata['user_nicename'] variable. So an example filter would go like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_nicename', 'my_nicename_modification');
function my_nicename_modification($userdata) {
    /*do anything you want with $userdata['user_nicename'] here
    or leave blank if you want it saved just as the user typed it in */
    return $userdata['user_nicename'];
}
```

This will stop `$user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user_nicename );` from running, on which you can read more on here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title. That is that modifies the nicename as you explained in your question. Hope this helps

Comment: function my_nicename_modification($userdata['user_nicename']) {
} is throwing an error. i am not getting the unsanitized nicename here.

Comment: We are getting the sanitized nicenameinside the filter, not $userdata variable.

Comment: You are right, we cannot access the $userdata variable from there and I cannot seem to find an action or filter to access it before. Curious if someone else finds something.